# Control point border thickness in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, border, point, thickness

When using ggplot, I can set `shape` to 21-25 to get shapes that have independent setting for the internal (`fill`) and border (`col`) colors, like so:

```
df <- data.frame(id=runif(12), x=1:12, y=runif(12))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill=id, size=id), colour="black", shape=21)
```

[image]

However, I can't figure out how to control the thickness of the shape borders, either setting them absolutely or as an aesthetic mapping.  I note that if I set an `lwd` value, it overrides the `size` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill=id, size=id), colour="black", shape=21, lwd=2)
```

[image]

How do I control the border thickness?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Starting in version 2.0.0 of **ggplot2**, there is an argument to control point border thickness.  From the `NEWS.md` file:

> geom_point() gains a stroke aesthetic which controls the border width of shapes 21-25 (#1133, @SeySayux). size and stroke are additive so a point with size = 5 and stroke = 5 will have a diameter of 10mm. (#1142)

Thus, the correct solution to this is now:

```
df <- data.frame(id=runif(12), x=1:12, y=runif(12))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(fill=id, size=id), colour="black", shape=21, stroke = 2)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you add the output?

Comment: For future compatibility and clarity it would be nice to say "Starting in version x.xx" rather than "the latest version".

Comment: Is there a way of controlling the thickness of the stroke based on the variables? Something along the lines of  "scale_stroke_manual"?

Comment: As a response to my own comment above, we can use scale_discrete_manual. See link here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3507#issuecomment-526212978

Comment: Any ideas why stroke=0 still draws it in PDF but not in PNG?

Answer (score 19):

It feels a bit hacky but you can add a "*background*" set of dots with the size set to the aesthetic mapping plus some small constant to *enlarge* the border of the dots. Play with the constant to get the desired border width.

You'll also have to disable the size legend to stop it displaying the legend on the graph...

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=id+0.5), colour="black" , show_guide = FALSE )+
  scale_size( guide = "none" )+
  geom_point(aes(fill=id, size=id), colour="black", shape=21)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe hackey, but Hadley endorsed this method on Twitter

Comment: @NoamRoss do you have the link for that?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create the plot in R and then export it to a .svg file. The linewidth can then be changed using vector graphics editing software (e.g., Inkscape). This method is particularly useful when data points overlap.