# Thickness of geom_point outline in ggplot2 where points are dynamically sized

Tags: r, ggplot2, point

I have what should be a relatively simple x/y scatterplot where I'm specifying a lot of aesthetics of the geom_point. I have figured out how to make the outline (colour), fill, and size of each point look more or less how I want. The problem is that I can't figure out how to specify the thickness of the outline (specified by colour); I need it to be hopefully just a liiiitle bit thicker for better visibility, and ideally, the alpha transparency which I need on the fill would not apply to the outline (i.e., the outline would be opaque while the fill would be somewhat transparent).

I have tried using another geom_point(), but the problem is calling this outside of an aes() I can't specify the size as alinf$Size.

Here is the code:

```
ggplot(alinf,aes(EffFreq,IRProp))+
   ylim(0,1.02)+
   scale_x_log10()+
   guides(fill=FALSE)+
   geom_point(aes(fill=Class,size=Size),color="black",shape=21,alpha=0.5)+
   scale_size(range=c(3,20))+
   scale_shape_identity()
```

And [this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAYEu.jpg), where I would ideally like thicker opaque outlines (sorry for the link, but my reputation is insufficient to post an image within the question).

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19506752/1478381) I wrote not so long ago.