# ggplot2 ggsave pdf solid lines around transparent boxes

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I want to compare different peaks from histograms, so I put two of them into one plot with alpha=0.5. The default output in RStudio looks fine, but when I use pdf() or ggsave() or even CairoPDF() the resulting output has solid lines around the boxes. In my case these solid lines sometimes look very ugly when zooming the pdf display. I want to disable these solid lines or at least have the lines to be the same color/alpha as the filling.

Minimal Code Example:

```
library(ggplot2)

p1<-ggplot()+
  geom_histogram(data=diamonds[diamonds$cut == "Premium",],aes(x=depth,fill=cut),alpha=0.5)+
  geom_histogram(data=diamonds[diamonds$cut == "Ideal",],aes(x=depth,fill=cut),alpha=0.5)

ggsave("histoline.pdf",p1)
```

this is the output:

[image]

I have tried various ways to modify linetypes and sizes but have not succeeded until now.

Comment: Have you tried [size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878848/control-bar-border-color-thickness-with-ggplot2-stroke)?

Comment: Same result for size=0, no Output for size=-1 and size=NA =(

Comment: linetype="blank" doesn't work for me either

Comment: hmmm, maybe the bars are overlapping a tiny bit?

Comment: when I zoom in to 6400% a gap becomes visible

Comment: I think the bins are overlapping a tiny bit. I did post this to the [ggplot2 mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/-qKNaeT-Hns). Maybe there is a cleaner way to set bin positions? I don't know how ggplot handles pdf output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A workaround is to compute the histogram manually and use ggplot to display the corresponding polygon only. It looks like what I want, but of course thats some extra lines of code and you lose a lot of ggplot functionality. Note: hist() and geom_hist() treat bin widths a little differently.

```
library(ggplot2)


hP <-hist(diamonds[diamonds$cut == "Premium",]$depth,breaks=seq(43,68,1))
hPd<-data.frame(breaks=c(hP$breaks[-1],hP$breaks),counts=c(hP$counts,hP$counts,hP$counts[1]))
hPd<-hPd[order(hPd$breaks),]

hI <- hist(diamonds[diamonds$cut == "Ideal",]$depth,breaks=seq(43,68,1))
hId<-data.frame(breaks=c(hI$breaks[-1],hI$breaks),counts=c(hI$counts,hI$counts,hI$counts[1]))
hId<-hId[order(hId$breaks),]

p1<-ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=hPd,aes(x=breaks,y=counts),fill="blue",alpha=0.5)+
  geom_polygon(data=hId,aes(x=breaks,y=counts),fill="red",alpha=0.5)
  #  this should yield the same binning behaviour as hist()
  #  geom_histogram(data=diamonds[diamonds$cut == "Premium",]
                  #,aes(x=depth),fill="green",binwidth=1,center=0.5,alpha=0.5)

print(p1)

ggsave("histoline.pdf",p1)
```

Comment: lets call it a work around. It looks like what I want to have, but the way there is not very elegant